# 404 when CoockieService (Angular2-Cookie) provider gets added

Tags: cookies, typescript, angular, http-status-code-404

I would like to use cookies in my Angular 2 project and tried to implement `angular2-cookie` in my project. I followed the instructions from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie#usage).

This is my current code:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/fragen/fragen.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class FragenComponent implements OnDestroy {
    public pageTitle: string = 'Wettbewerbs Fragen';
}
```

When I add `providers: [CookieService]` i get a 404 (Not Found) Error in the browser console.

I installed `angular2-cookie/core` correctly with npm and I am using TypeScript.

It also doesn^t work when I add a constructor like so:

```
constructor(private _cookieService:CookieService){}
```

The error message:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:126 GET http://localhost:3000/angular2-cookie/core 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:126ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:403Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:340(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:147send @ VM34076:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1154(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1735ZoneAwarePromise @ angular2-polyfills.js:648(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1734(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:2759(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3333(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3600(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:3985(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4448(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:4700(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:406ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:390Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:283(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:635ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:423Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:320drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:541ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:493

angular2-polyfills.js:390 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angular2-cookie/core(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:390Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:283(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:635ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:423Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:320drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:541ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:493
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: Did you run `npm install angular2-cookie --save`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, i did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you forgot to configure the library in SystemJS:

```
var map = {
  'app':                        'app', // 'dist', 
  'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
  '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
  'angular2-cookie':            'node_modules/angular2-cookie', // <----
};

var packages = {
  'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-cookie':            { main: 'core.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' }, // <-----------
  'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

Note that a bundled file is also provided for the library:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2-cookie/bundles/angular2-cookie.js"></script>
```

Moreover this file contains module names with the js extension so you need to import its core module this way:

```
import from 'angular2-cookie/core.js';
```

I think that the first approach is the best...

Comment: Where can I find the SystemJS? I can't find it... :/

Comment: I use npm and I used the started [this](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM%20-%20Start) starter template.

Comment: Yes, fine! But it seems that angular2-cookie requires rc version(s) of Angular2. So you need to update the `System.config` block in your index.html file. See this link for more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#systemjs.

Comment: Am I understanding this right that i should change the inner of the script tags to the code you posted above?

Comment: What do you mean with rc version?

Comment: Not beta one (beta.17 for example) but a release candidate one (rc1 for example). Names of modules changed between them: `angular2/core` to `@angular/core` for example and there is no bundled version (yet) of Angular2 for rc versions.

Comment: I replaced the inner of the script tags with your code above and now the page doesn't get displayed and there is no error on the console output...

Comment: The code I provided is an extract of the configuration in fact. See this page: angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#systemjs. And you need this in your HTML file (from the same doc): `<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err);  });
    </script>`

Comment: I also have this issue, looks like the recent change in angular2 rc causes the issue, I executed ALL steps from other tutorial (npm install, configure angular cli + system js) but it s not working